# How to get AWS instance total memory size using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to run a python startup script inside AWS instance in which I want to get the total memory size selected during instance creation.

I have tried `free -h` , `grep MemTotal` `/proc/meminfo` commands. But, the problem with these commands is, I get some less amount of RAM than the actual memory size I selected while creating an instance (due to system use maybe). I want to get the exact memory size I selected while creating an instance. e.g., "2 GB" for "t2.small" , "4 GB" for "c5.large" ,etc.

Also, there is no metadata URL available to get AWS instance memory size.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but I think the process might be something like:

client = boto3.client('ec2')

type = client.describe_instance_attribute(Attribute='instanceType', InstanceId='YOUR_ID' )

details = client.describe_instance_types( InstanceTypes=[ type ] )

memory = details['InstanceTypes']['MemoryInfo']['SizeInMiB']

You'll need to give the instance the right IAM permissions to get the data (it's not the same as the http://169.254.169.254 metadata).

You can also get the instance type from http://169.254.169.254/2020-10-27/meta-data/instance-type/ but I'm trying to go for a fully python solution with boto3.

Comment: Hey @Oscar De León ,   it worked for me ,,, thanks :)